# OData select with complex data type

Tags: select, odata, complex-data-types

I want to retrieve a single property from a complex data type.

Platform: EF Core 6, OData V4, Blazor on Windows 11, VS 2022 on a MS SQL Express database.

Simplified DB / entity structure:

```
[Owned]
public class FileInfo
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Filename { get; set };
}

public class UserInfo
{
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DocumentID { get; set; }

    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string OwnerID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserInfo? Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Request 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid RequestID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string AuthorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorID")]
    public virtual UserInfo? Author;

    public Guid DocumentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentID")]
    public virtual Document? Document;
}
```

Entities etc.:

```
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Document>("Documents");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Request>("Requests");
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<FileInfo>();
    return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Query #1:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestApp/Requests?
    $count=true&
    $select=Document&
    $orderby=Document/FileInfo/Filename&
    $expand=Document($select=FileInfo/Filename)
```

This query returns:

```
 {"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/
  $metadata#Requests(Document,Document(FileInfo/Filename))",
  "@ odata.count":3,"value":[
      {"Document":{"FileInfo":{"Filename":"BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf"}}},
      {"Document":{"FileInfo":{"Filename":"BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf"}}},
      {"Document":{"FileInfo":{"Filename":"BST-DEF-DD100-01.PDF"}}}]}
```

However, I actually only need a list of strings (the property values).

This is not all though. Things are getting ugly when I apply a filter to the query, requiring me to look at and hence expand more data:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestApp/Requests?
  $count=true&$orderby=Document/FileInfo/Filename&
  $select=Document&
  $filter=(Document/OwnerID eq 'Testuser') or (AuthorID eq 'TestUser')&
  $expand=Author,Document($expand=Owner;$select=FileInfo/Filename)
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:12345/TestApp/
 $metadata#Requests(
     Document,Author(),
     Document(FileInfo/Filename,
     Owner()))",
 "@odata.count":1,
 "value":[
     {"Author":{"Name":"Test User"},
      "Document":{"FileInfo":{"Filename":"Test.PDF"},
      "Owner":{"Name":"Test User"}}}]}
```

*Note: Using "$select=" instead of "$select=Document" returns all property values of Document (seems to be treated like "select * from Documents").*

How do I need to adjust the query to only return Request.Document.FileInfo.Filename?

I did google and also searched SO for an answer, but couldn't find one.

Comment: You should document the specific output structure you are expecting, and some supporting information on why you need this and why the default output does not suffice. There are simple `Function` and `Action` implementations that are available to you, but we cannot provide example code if you do not document your controller endpoint as a base.

Answer (score 1):

> **Update:** Thankyou for updating the post with the platform/vendor version, that changes everything, you are not asking about *standards* anymore but about a specific implementation, which is the correct approach.

You are correct that to `$select` a specific property on a *ComplexType* you should use the `/` to address it as a descendant of the name of the root property:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestApp/Requests?
    $count=true&
    $select=Document&
    $orderby=Document/FileInfo/Filename&
    $expand=Document($select=FileInfo/Filename)
```

> **NOTE:** Some server-side implementations or constraints might require that certain fields are returned, even if you do not request them. This is a server-side configuration and is outside of the scope of the specifications. The specs do not specifically state that non-requested fields cannot be returned, only that the requested fields *MUST* be included in the response. Custom implementations are allowed to return additional properties as long as they are declared correctly in the `$metadata` then they will be supported.

Unfortunately for your case a key tenant of OData V4 over other APIs is that the structure of the resource will not change. *Entities* are *resources* (the **R** in *REST*) and OOTB in the .Net implementations this cannot be violated. This means that the response will always be an array of `Request` objects that have a single `Document` property that also has a single `FileInfo` that has a single `Filename` property.

- So from a pure OData v4 specification point of view, what you are asking for is totally against the core principle of OData (v4), read on for additional variations and exceptions to this rule...

> RE: This is not all though. Things are getting ugly when I apply a filter to the query, requiring me to look at and hence expand more data:

There is no reason that you *need* to include other `$expand` or `$select` properties to evaluate a `$filter`. `$filter` is evaluated first and *independently* from (and before) the `$select` and `$expand`. So you are not *required* to include these properties in your request at all, but if you do include those navigation pathways in the request, it makes sense that those fields and/or navigation properties would be included in the response.

If you query the `Requests` controller, then according to the OData specification, the response *should* be in the shape of a `Response` object. We can used `$select` and `$expand` to reduce the bytes transferred over the wire by omitting properties, but relationship structure or general *shape* of the object graph MUST be maintained to allow the client-side implementations to work correctly.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/$metadata#Requests(Document,Document(FileInfo/Filename))",
  "@ odata.count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "Document": {
        "FileInfo": {
          "Filename": "BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Document": {
        "FileInfo": {
          "Filename": "BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Document": {
        "FileInfo": {
          "Filename": "BST-DEF-DD100-01.PDF"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you are expecting a simple OData array of strings like the following, then you will have to write some extra code:

```
{ 
  "value": [
    "BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf",
    "BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf",
    "BST-DEF-DD100-01.PDF"
  ]
}
```

or perhaps, if you want a pure custom REST/JSON response you can do that too, but it's not conformant to the OData specification anymore:

```
[
  "BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf",
  "BST-abc-dd100-04.pdf",
  "BST-DEF-DD100-01.PDF"
]
```

> Previous versions of OData did support direct querying of child resources, but in v4 specification this is only supported by Entity navigation links

You OData controllers are just a great start for whatever you want to add to your OData implementation. If you have a genuine need to return a flattened list, then you can add an additional function to your controller to support this,

There is a feature described in the [OData 4.01 amended specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_SystemQueryOptioncompute) that does allow you to use an *alias* to reference the result of a `$compute` query option. However, this was not included in the specification until 2020, not many older implementations are likely to have support for this new option, EF Core (Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.0.12) only has partial support for this syntax.

It is expected to work like this:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestApp/Requests?
    $count=true&
    $select=File&
    $orderby=File&
    $compute=Document/FileInfo/Filename as File
```

Should result in something similar to this:

```
{"@odata.context":"...",
 "@odata.count":3,"value":
 [{"File":"test1.pdf"},
  {"File":"test2.pdf"},
  {"File":"test3.PDF"}
 ]}
```

Unfortunately as I test this I encounter a bug in Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.0.12 that does not allow you to `$select` the aliased column, you can see the column included if you use `$select=*` but I cannot scope the response to just that column.

Please try it on your API to confirm, but until $compute works if you have need of a specific shape of data, then you should add a *function* or *action* endpoint to return that desired data. OData is just a tool to help you get there, using OData does not preclude you from adding custom endpoints, as long as you define them correctly, they will still be exposed through the metadata and can be easily consumed by clients that implement code generators.

To implement a custom function to retrieve this data, you can use a controller method similar to this:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Filenames()
{
    IQueryable<Request> query = GetRequestsQuery();
    return Ok(query.Select(x => x.Document.FileInfo.Filename).ToArray());
}
...
        
builder.EntitySet<Request>("Requests").EntityType.Collection.Function(nameof(Filenames)).ReturnsCollection<string>();
```

Then you could query this via the following URL:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestApp/Requests/Filenames
```

However OData Query Options can only be enforced on the *response* type of the method, so even with `[EnableQuery]` OOTB you can only `$filter`  or `$orderby` the values in the `Filename` property.

There are other workarounds, including Open Type support, but if you are interested in the `$compute` solution but cannot get it to work, then we should raise an issue with https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues?q=compute to get the wider community involved.

Comment: I tried that. For me, $select= returns all of the records' data. It seems to be treated like "SELECT * from ...". What makes this worse is that expanding additional nested properties includes all their data in the response. I tried "expand=Author($select=)", but again got all Author data included.

Comment: That is not part of the specification, but a factor of your API's specific implementation... When we are dealing with an Implementation that isn't faithful to the specification, this becomes a very specific question for the vendor or your developers, and cannot be answered in a forum like this that is dealing with _standards_. In your investigations, you shouldn't be able to specify `Document` in the root entity `$select` because it is a navigation property, only _ComplexType_ and _primitive_ valued properties can be referenced in a `$select`

Comment: I am using EF Core 6 and Blazor plus OData V4, so I guess the OData implementation is from Microsoft. Is this a known behavior of MS's OData implementation?

Comment: @Razzupaltuff I can confirm your behaviour, in EF Core (.Net 5/6). The `$select=` works in .Net 4.8 OData implementations.

Comment: And again, MS believed they are smarter than the rest of the world ... only they are not. >:(

Comment: It's an open source project, anyone of us could submit a PR for this, but no one really needs it, not when we can replicate the functionality with custom functions or endpoints to return specific graphs that don't match the entity resource. This is the standard solution for custom DTOs, which the really is.

Comment: First of all, we are talking about a specific implementation and not the OData standard in general, and you yourself stated that allowing something like "$select=<class name>" is a deviation from the standard. So I wouldn't know why I should start working on the standard. On the other hand, since the problem at hand seems to be specific to the - proprietary - MS implementation, what makes you think I could implement changes to that? Also, "No one really needs it" is a bit too much of a generalization I believe. You may want to stay a bit more reasonable here.

Comment: Adding generic support for this feature is not complicated, as the implementation is fully customisable. It is however more code than adding a few custom endpoints to satisfy your specific business needs. A good OData solution doesn't rely on the client queryable aspect alone so take this opportunity to explore how to support it as a first class feature of your implementation

Comment: Even if I would start working on the OData implementation, I would need my changes to make it into the official standard. So what makes you believe that would happen, and even less happen in a time frame that suits my immediate project needs? Contrary to my asking you to stay reasonable, you went totally off the wall here.

Comment: You don't need the standards to change, it's your API, the standards are simply a guideline, not many APIs are 100% compliant, but you can add any additional features that you can justify, just add a custom routing convention like we can to support `/$value`. It is your API you can do what you want. I'm not here to judge why you want to do a non-standard query, but if you really need it, just go for it, but by doing so that is no longer an OData request, but a simpler REST request.

Comment: My query isn't non standard. My application needs to be installed at a big customer, and I won't be going to dig into OData frameworks, trying to figure interfaces and change behaviours for months in order to create a specialized, more or less private OData library. The root problem is that "$select=" includes all data properties instead of omitting them all. The shape of the result isn't crucial here; The point is that I want to have as little data transferred as possible.

Comment: So `$select` the _Key_ column in the request, or add the 10 lines of code for an OData _Function_ (which is part of the standard) or add the 20 lines of code to support `select=` to minimise the results. Otherwise make FileInfo an Entity, not a Complex Type. It is sort of out of scope for this post but I can include an example of a function if that will help you

Comment: I have held myself back until now, but enough is enough. You have been no help at all so far, and I am tired of your patronizing, arrogant tone and over generalizing comments that have no real relation to what I am saying or trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't do what you want without adding some custom code, adding a new function endpoint is the simplest option, but the SDK is open source so you can modify the implementation as you need to. There are so many options but I don't really feel like putting in the hours to show you good examples and document in a way that you might be willing to consume. I'm expecting responses like, "OK, cool, what would that look like". You could also change the client end to suit what OData v4 can return. Defining a function is the right solution in this case.

Comment: I expected an answer that doesn't lead to an end- and fruitless, over generalizing discussion. I was actually done when I read that MS' implementation of '$select=' is non standard. That caused me to develop a different approach to satisfy my requirement which I already have in place. Unlike yours, my focus is not on OData, but on my concrete application and the timeline I have for it. If you have ever done project work you will understand that it is beyond the scope of a customer project to start tinkering with mighty frameworks and building custom versions of them to fix their behavior.

Comment: I understand that you put a lot of effort into your reply and comments, but I feel like you are trying to help me cross a street I never wanted cross (pun intended).

Comment: The underlying query is rather complex and cannot be broken down into simpler queries each of which is consumed by its own endpoint. The reason for that is that it is used by a 3rd party software (Syncfusion). The solution was to create a single endpoint with additional parameters that executes complex queries depending on these parameters. This makes the query for Syncfusion's API rather simple and just adds a few parameters to it.

Comment: The elegance of an OData solution would have been that OData would have done all the dirty work of joining tables and filtering data for me, all with a from my point of view quite straightforward filter.

Comment: I love syncfusion, and OData because of it, not the other way around. OData is a great base to build your API from, I have 120 tables and maybe less than 2000 lines of custom code to expose it to the world. You get 95% of the dirty work OOTB. I have complex needs, as does anyone, but to expose views and custom queries in a way that clients can automatically consume them is so powerful. If you have a specific issue, from the client then document it, it rather sounds like you have misinterpreted a lot and I'd love to help you out. Syncfusion doesn't handle complex types well but there is a way.

Comment: I've revisited this after installing the latest version, `$compute` is not 100% what you want, but gee wiz are we getting close. I still maintain what you are asking for is specifically not supported by OData v4 on purpose. `$compute` gets as close to a generic solution as we'll ever get, but in the last 10 years with v4 on commercial sites I haven't needed to change the shape and have come to rely on this rule, so lets explore the other end, why you think you need it because I'm sure there is an alternate solution to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250417/discussion-between-razzupaltuff-and-chris-schaller).